# sencha generate app failing from INSIDE SDK FOLDER

Tags: sencha-touch

I issued this command:

sencha generate app LaBucaDiSanMatteo c:\xampp\htdocs\LaBucaDiSanMatteo

from inside SDK folder (c:\touch-2.3.1).

I got:
 [INF] Workspace does not have framework null at C:\xampp\htdocs\LaBucaDiSanMatteo ... copying
 [ERR] Failed to determine framework name. Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory

I'm using Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.

Sencha CMD works only with the GPL version. Not working with the free commercial version.
I downloaded the first by mistake. I discovered the problem comparing the 2.3 with the old 2.2.1 (luckily I kept a copy).